# Cell appears to be empty but keeps saying it contains values in it

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have this formula in a cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE( REGEXREPLACE(REGEXEXTRACT(INDIRECT("C2:C"&COUNTA(C2:C)+1), REPT("(.)", LEN(INDIRECT("C2:C"&COUNTA(C2:C)+1)))), "['A-Za-z\.-]", )),,999^99)),,999^99), " "))))
```

[image]

When no diacritics appear in the search column, the cell was supposed to be empty, but when you copy that cell to another, it comes back as if there were values in it, it seems to be several spaces together.

[image]

When using the `LEN` function, it also appears to have values, but apparently it's empty ... And that's how I would really like it to be, totally empty if I didn't find diacritics in the list names

I would like a help so that it really gets empty when not finding diacritics

Here is the link to the spreadsheet if it becomes easier to understand the situation:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yfB8GskVU_ciFKuzae9XQF-pi3y6jsYtsanN46vmNOs/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add `TRIM` to fix this issue:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE( 
 REGEXREPLACE(REGEXEXTRACT(INDIRECT("C2:C"&COUNTA(C2:C)+1), REPT("(.)", 
 LEN(INDIRECT("C2:C"&COUNTA(C2:C)+1)))), "['A-Za-z\.-]", )),,999^99)),,999^99), " ")))))
```

[image: 0]